# Masonry not working when I press the accordion (height doesn't increases)

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, masonry

I have an accordion inside a div called card (I use Foundation 6). I tried to apply Masonry (https://masonry.desandro.com) and it didn't worked. The masonry doesn't understand when I open an accordion.

https://youtu.be/mXNbJ5bjg88

The code: https://codepen.io/yeltsinxyz/pen/porwbbN

```
        <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x medium-up-2 small-up-1 large-up-3 locais-cards align-stretch">

            <div class="cell">

              <div class="card">

                <img src="img/sobremesa1.jpg" alt="">

                <div class="card-section">

                  <ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true">
                    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
                      <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Sorvete</a>
                      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, voluptatum tempora doloremque sapiente iste deserunt ex excepturi totam quo natus expedita amet ducimus alias repellendus dolorem ut mollitia dolore nemo?</p>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
                      <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Restaurante</a>
                      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, voluptatum tempora doloremque sapiente iste deserunt ex excepturi totam quo natus expedita amet ducimus alias repellendus dolorem ut mollitia dolore nemo?</p>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
                      <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Como Chegar</a>
                      <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi, voluptatum tempora doloremque sapiente iste deserunt ex excepturi totam quo natus expedita amet ducimus alias repellendus dolorem ut mollitia dolore nemo?</p>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

              </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

JS

```
$(document).foundation();

$(window).on('load', function(){
  $('.locais-cards').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.locais-cards .cell'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the `masonry` when an accordion is opened or closed, so you need to react to the

- `down.zf.accordion`
- `up.zf.accordion`

events as described in https://get.foundation/sites/docs/accordion.html#js-events

So, for your specific example you need to use

```
$(document).on('down.zf.accordion up.zf.accordion',()=>{
  $('.locais-cards').masonry();
});
```

Updated demo: https://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/dyzRXjL